# custom pagination in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I try to make custom pagination like this `1,2,3....10`, is it possible to make pagination like that with `<?php wp_link_pages( $args ); ?>` ? I don't know how to make these dots, so that they not will be links.

Answer (score 0):

If can Create a function for this and use for reference you can check here.

http://zeo.my/native-pagination-plugins-wordpress/

even some plugin is also available you can use that. i am trying to solve your problem hope

this helps

Thanks
Anand